# nginx fastcgi get SSL information?

Tags: ssl, nginx, fastcgi

I have a fastcgi app and I like to use client certifications with it. How do I get the certificate information? I am mostly only interested in the common name and serial number. Nginx seems to give error pages on invalid or missing certs which is fine.

How do I get this information in my fastcgi app?

Answer (score 3):

Basically, you can retrieve the client SSL certificate with

```
fastcgi_param SSL_CLIENT_CERT $ssl_client_raw_cert if_not_empty;
```

If you need more variables or a strict compatibility with Apache, you can find a port to nginx of the standard Apache SSL variables: https://github.com/Seb35/nginx-ssl-variables (not completely finished as of now).

With this installed, your application will see the same variables as with Apache. nginx gives native access to some variables, but you will need Lua and Lua-OpenSSL to have more variables.