# SSL client certificate configuration nginx

Tags: nginx, ssl, ssl-certificate

So I have a location (/client/Bundle) that is accessible by a third website by presenting a client certificate. Only then the TLS handshake can take place. I need to check if a certificate is presented & verify this presented certificate.

So I set up the following in my NGINX config:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name mywebsite.nl;

    # Enable client certificate authentication
    ssl_client_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/client_nl/certificate.crt;
    ssl_verify_client on;

    
    location mywebsite.nl/client/Bundle {
        # Pass the request to PHP-FPM for processing
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
       
    }
}
```

In PHP, I validate the certificate using a simple if statement

```
if (isset($_SERVER['SSL_CLIENT_CERT']) && !empty($_SERVER['SSL_CLIENT_CERT'])) {
//everything alright, execute code
}
else {
      abort (403);
}
```

However, this does not work as the **$_SERVER['SSL_CLIENT_CERT']** variable is always empty.

What am I doing wrong here?

There is already an answer here [nginx fastcgi get SSL information?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21656497/nginx-fastcgi-get-ssl-information)
But adding

```
fastcgi_param SSL_CLIENT_CERT $ssl_client_raw_cert if_not_empty;
```

to the Nginx conf file does not change anything. The variable is still empty.

Even when I use the following in my conf file, it simply ignores whether a certificate is given or not and shows me the page instead of a 403:

```
location /client/Bundle {
     
        if ($ssl_client_verify != SUCCESS) {
            return 403;
        }

   
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME       $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
```

Comment: The changed config shows that you've added SCRIPT_FILENAME as variable but not SSL_CLIENT_CERT. *"it simply ignores whether a certificate is given or not"* - since the client certificate is not set as optional there should be an error generated by nginx if no certificate is given - that's at least what it does for me. How exactly do you test?

Comment: I test using Postman with the certificate added into Postman. However, since there is no certificate, I get returned a status 403. Have you added SSL_CLIENT_CERT and it works for you?

Comment: Yes, it works for me. I get a "400 Bad Request ... No required SSL certificate was sent" back from nginx when no client certificate is given. Similar error with different text when a client certificate was given which could not be validated. When a proper client certificate is given  then `$_SERVER['SSL_CLIENT_CERT'] ` contains the PEM of the certificate as expected.

Comment: Hmm weird, the client certificate is presented, but I still get 400 bad request. Is there any way I can test a client certificate?

Comment: What is the full error you get back? Have you checked the server logs?